# SharePoint Reporting

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I've created a bunch of Lists for users to enter data.  Now it's time to start creating useful reports. All reports must be in SharePoint so we can't export to Excel or use SSRS.  I created a SP-Report Center, now could someone plese help me create and link reports to the data the users enter in the lists?  I do not have SharePoint Designer "yet"  Thank you.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as "reports" can mean a lot of different things.  By default, the only reporting SharePoint has are the Views on individual lists.

Comment: You can use Sharepoint lists as datasources in SSRS.

Comment: And then in turn display them back in SharePoint with either the report view web parts or via URL execution.

Answer (score 2):

For SharePoint Foundation:

- You can create Dashboard pages using [WebPart Connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178187.aspx).
- You can use [ChartPart for SharePoint](http://chartpart.codeplex.com/) opensource project by Wictor Wilén to display charts based on lists information.
- For displaying cross-list information, use Data View Web Part, and create cross-list datasources for it (SharePoint Designer has GUI for this).

For SharePoint Server, there are at least two additional great features. Yes, I've noticed the `sharepoint-foundation` tag, but just can't resist to mention :)

- [Excel Services](http://%20-%20Excel%20Services%20will%20show%20Excel%20reports%20from%20within%20SharePoint%20portal,%20allowing%20users%20to%20perform%20some%20basic%20operations%20like%20filtering%20and%20sorting.%20And%20the%20Excel%20reports%20are%20stored%20in%20SharePoint%20libraries.%20So%20I%20reckon,%20Excel%20Services%20are%20a%20SharePoint-way%20solution%20too.) will show Excel reports from within SharePoint portal, allowing users to perform some basic operations like filtering and sorting. And the Excel reports are stored in SharePoint libraries. So I reckon, Excel Services are a SharePoint-way solution too.
- You can use [Content Query Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/display-a-dynamic-view-of-content-on-a-page-by-adding-the-content-query-web-part-HA101794897.aspx?CTT=1) to aggregate information from different lists.

Answer (score 2):

My approach for ur query would be :

Complex and more in-detailed way of reporting:

1. Use **sharepoint list data source** existing in sql server 2008 r2 and create SSRS or performance point based dashboards and reports

Simplest and OOTB based way of reporting:

1. Use chart web part and display the content in different formats or use excel services to render the charts or dashboards via excel web access webpart.
2. If not customize using sharepint desginer via dataview web parts or else right ur own queries leveraging linq with sp object model and display the dash boards\charts in user controls or web parts.